# Is a continuous function $f : \mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}$ always bounded on a closed interval?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, rational-numbers

Can a function $f : \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$ that is continuous on an interval $[a,b]$ not be bounded on $[a,b]$? I'm asking this because in Spivak's *Calculus*, the "Boundedness Theorem", which states that any real-valued function that is continuous on a closed interval is bounded on that interval, is proved using the properties of real numbers. However, I cannot think of a counterexample in which it fails for rationals.

Comment: Oh,  I am sorry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps a simpler example than the one given by Daniel,

$$f(x)=\frac1{x^2-2}$$

It is not hard to show that this function is continuous on every rational number (simply note that it is continuous on $\Bbb R\setminus\{\pm\sqrt2\}$ and so its restriction is continuous). But it is not bounded on the interval $[1,2]$.

Comment: Nice and Dimple.

Comment: Mice and Wimple.

Comment: Rice and Pimple.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I'd drink Wimple or Pimple.

Comment: @Daniel: And I don't think that I'd drink blended scotch.

Comment: Oh, drat, they don't have a single malt? I am disappointed.

Answer (score 10):

Define $f\colon \mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{Q}$ by

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 &, x \leqslant 0 \\ 1 &, x > \pi^{-1} \\ k &, \pi^{-1} - \pi^{-k} < x < \pi^{-1} - \pi^{-k-1},\end{cases}$$

where $k\in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$. Since the jumps of $f$ are at the irrational points $\pi^{-1} - \pi^{-k},\, k \geqslant 2$ and at $\pi^{-1}$, $f$ is continuous, and $f$ is unbounded on $[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @JohnMa Oops. Thanks. Gotta fix that.

Comment: Isn't it bounded between 1 and $k$?

Comment: @moni94 $k$ becomes arbitrarily large. For every $k$, we have $\pi^{-1} - \pi^{-k-1} < \pi^{-1}$, and the interval $(\pi^{-1} - \pi^{-k-1}, \pi^{-1} - \pi^{-k-2})$ contains rational numbers at which the value is $k+1$.

Comment: I call your example, and raise you by a nicer presentation!

Comment: An interesting corollary of your example is that $[0,1]\cap \mathbb Q$ is not a compact set in $\mathbb Q$